# cannot find reference to charfield

Tags: django

i made a model of music  with 2 classes album and song and code is provided below but my error code shows-
 Album-models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ModelBase' and 'ForeignKey'

i just started django so go easy on the answers

```
from django.db import models

class Album(models.Model):
    artist=models.Charfield(max_length=250)
    album_title=models.Charfield(max_length=500)
    genre=models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    album_logo=models.Charfield(max_length=1000)

class Song(models.Model):
    album-models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type=models.Charfield(max_length=10)
    song_title=models.Charfield(max_length=250)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `Charfield` to `CharField`
Also in `Song` model correct this:

```
album=models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: now my error cade is- Album-models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ModelBase' and 'ForeignKey'

Comment: Replace by this line `album=models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually its `CharField()` instead of `Charfield()`, because django follows Capital Camel Casing

so you `Album` model should look like

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: now my error code says this- Album-models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ModelBase' and 'ForeignKey'